# Update every x time a board in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I need update my board based on an array of board states every x time, I try to use setTimeout() but the board only takes the finall state in the array

```
nextSteps(){
 for(let i = 0; i < this.nextStates.length; i++)
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.cells = this.nextStates[i]//Cells is the state of the board
      console.log("changed")
  }, 220*i)   
}
```

I'm using vue js for track the changes of the valu of the data, there are my definition

```
data(){
 return{
  cells: [

  ],
  nextStates: [

  ],
  steps: 75,
 }
},
```

and here where I render them

```
<div class="mainGrid">
  <table class="board">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in cells" :key="row.id">
        <td :class="'cell-'+cell.state" v-for="cell in row" :key="cell.id"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add data examples of `cells` and `nextStates`? You are assigning an element of array to array (`this.cells = this.nextStates[i]`)

Comment: cells is an array of rows (arrays of cell obejcts)  Array(60)
0:
state: 0
row: 0
col: 0
1:
state: (...)
row: (...)
col: (...)                                                                                                                        and nextStates is an array of cells @cereme

Comment: If you want to make change to array or object, you should not use direct assigning. Check this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: watch the project repo (the asyncBoard branch) [link](https://github.com/PaoloTorregroza/game-of-life/tree/asyncBoard)

Comment: Ok I go to see it